# Navigation Bar back button action performing even after the button also

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

It is looks like a very simple question But i do not know where the mistake is.
I have an navigation bar i am placing a custom nav bar back button 
The action is performed through out the "pink" color as shown in the image below

[image]

My code is below:

```
//-------back button  start
    UIImage *myImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"];
    UIButton *myButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [myButton1 setImage:myImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    myButton1.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
    myButton1.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 3.0, 40,30);
    [myButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton1];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;
    //-------back button  end
```

I tried even this way also like  "myButton1.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 3.0, 20,30);"

Even i tried by changing the button width and height also. Then it is decreasing the width of the back button only .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check once your image name spelled correct or not.

Comment: Check your image Back.png. It may have extra space..

Comment: yeah image is also the same size i.e, 40x30 . And also the name is also correct 
@Ganee....

Comment: i did not get u.. extra space means ? @Anusha

Comment: Pink color is in highlighted state of button no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your button size as image size.

```
myButton1.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 30.0,30.0);
```

And please check that you don't have any shadow and transparency around image.

Comment: Yeah.. i tried this one also.. i did not get . Thank u..... is there any other way. @Rajneesh071

Comment: navigation bar have height 44 and you are setting button fream to 40...so reduce it and check what image size u have

Comment: my image size is 30x30 @Rajneesh071

Comment: then y r u making 40 and 30..just make button frame 30,30

Comment: i did not give that.. Why i do .. I think u r not given any wrong answer. u just suggested me the way. @Rajneesh071